# Bootstrap 3 removing active class when hovering over another menu item

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a side dropdown menu that has three links with submenu items.  When I am on one of those sub pages, i add a 'hover' class to the parent ul making it stay open.  The problem is, when I hover over another menu link, that submenu still stays open, ultimately blocking the other submenu.  How can I remove the hover class to the current link when i hover over another menu item and add it again if i hover out of it?

This is the code I tried to no avail

```
$(function(){
$(".dropdown-submenu.hover").toggleClass("active",true);
});

$(function(){
$(".dropdown-submenu").on("hover",function(e) {
if($(e.currentTarget).hasClass("active"))
$(e.currentTarget).toggleClass("active",false);
else 
$(e.currentTarget).toggleClass("active",true);
e.preventDefault(); 
return false;
});
$(".dropdown-submenu").on("hide.bs.dropdown", doNothing);

$(".dropdown-submenu").on("show.bs.dropdown", doNothing);

function doNothing() {
e.preventDefault(); 
return false;
}
});
```

This is the html

```
    <div class="hidden-xs dropdown  col-sm-2 " id="sidebar" role="navigation">


            <button id="mainnav" class="btn-block mainmenu mainnav dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" data-autohide="false">Menu</button>
                <ul id="mainsubnav" class="nav dropdown-menu mainsubnav" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu">
                    <li class="dropdown-submenu"><a href="Main Link 1">Has Submenu 1</a>

                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="link1.php">Sublink 1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="link2.php">Sublink 1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="link3.php">Sublink 1</a></li>
                        </ul>

                    </li>
                    <li class="dropdown-submenu"><a href="Link 1">Has Submenu 2</a>

                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a class="active" href="link1.php">Sublink 2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="link2.php">Sublink 2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="link3.php">Sublink 2</a></li>
                        </ul>

                    </li>
                    <li class="dropdown-submenu"><a href="Link 1">Has Submenu 3</a>

                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="link1.php">Sublink 3</a></li>
                            <li><a href="link2.php">Sublink 3</a></li>
                            <li><a href="link3.php">Sublink 3</a></li>
                        </ul>

                    </li>
                    <li><a href="link">Link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="link">Link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="link">Link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="link">Link</a></li>

                </ul>




    </div><!--/#sidebar-->

</div>
```

and this is the code that adds the hover class

```
$('ul.dropdown-menu > li > a.active:first').closest('li.dropdown-submenu').addClass('hover');
$('ul.dropdown-menu > li > a.active:first').closest('li.dropdown-    submenu').children('a').addClass('active');
```

here is the example

http://www.bootply.com/hXsG8vzeDj

Comment: Try putting       $('.hover').removeClass('hover');  Before assigning the new one.

Comment: thank you @dvidsilva.  I updated the javascript but now I'm unable to go back to the default state of the open menu.  I sort of have it working with .off but not really.  Here's the updated example http://www.bootply.com/OggYeTSthK

Comment: Sorry @JS I just saw this notification. It seems that is working, or what do you want to accomplish?